# PHP: PayPal IPN does not insert data into MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I have the following PHP PayPal IPN which was working absolutely fine until a few days ago.

However, since lastnight, it suddenly stopped working and it doesn't matter how many times I test it in paypal sandbox ipn simulator, it just does not insert anything into MYSQL database!

I have not changed anything in my php file so I do not understand why this issue is occurring.

This is my entire code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

$murl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
// Check to see there are posted variables coming into the script
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") die ("No Post Variables");
// Initialize the $req variable and add CMD key value pair
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
// Read the post from PayPal
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Now Post all of that back to PayPal's server using curl, and validate everything with PayPal
// We will use CURL instead of PHP for this for a more universally operable script (fsockopen has issues on some environments)
//$url = $paypal_url;
$url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$curl_result=$curl_err='';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);
$curl_err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$req = str_replace("&", "\n", $req);  // Make it a nice list in case we want to email it to ourselves for reporting

// Check that the result verifies
if (strpos($curl_result, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
    $req .= "\n\nPaypal Verified OK";
} else {
    $req .= "\n\nData NOT verified from Paypal!";
    mail("myemail@yahoo.co.uk", "IPN interaction not verified", "$req", "From: myemail@yahoo.co.uk" );
    exit();
}

/* CHECK THESE 4 THINGS BEFORE PROCESSING THE TRANSACTION, HANDLE THEM AS YOU WISH
1. Make sure that business email returned is your business email
2. Make sure that the transactions payment status is completed
3. Make sure there are no duplicate txn_id
4. Make sure the payment amount matches what you charge for items. (Defeat Price-Jacking) */

// Check Number 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
include "config/connect.php";


$storePayment = "".$paypal_email."";

$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];

if ($receiver_email != $storePayment) {
    $message = "Investigate why and how receiver email is wrong. Email = " . $_POST['receiver_email'] . "\n\n\n$req";
    mail("myemail@yahoo.co.uk", "Receiver Email is incorrect", $message, "From: myemail@yahoo.co.uk" );
    exit(); // exit script
}
// Check number 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($_POST['payment_status'] != "Completed") {
    // Handle how you think you should if a payment is not complete yet, a few scenarios can cause a transaction to be incomplete
}
// Connect to database ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
require_once 'config/connect.php';
// Check number 3 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$this_txn = $_POST['txn_id'];

            $stmt = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT id
     FROM yt_transactions
     WHERE txn_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $this_txn);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($this_txn);
    $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows == 0)  //To check if the row exists
        {
            while($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row

              { 
    $message = "Duplicate transaction ID occured so we killed the IPN script. \n\n\n$req";
    mail("noreply@mrshopp.com", "Duplicate txn_id in the IPN system", $message, "From: noreply@mrshopp.com" );
    exit(); // exit script
               }

        }
        $stmt->close();


include "config/connect.php";

// Check number 4 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$product_id_string  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['custom']);
//$product_id_string = rtrim($product_id_string, ","); // remove last comma
// Explode the string, make it an array, then query all the prices out, add them up, and make sure they match the payment_gross amount
//$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_id_string); // Uses Comma(,) as delimiter(break point)

// END ALL SECURITY CHECKS NOW IN THE DATABASE IT GOES ------------------------------------
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Homework - Examples of assigning local variables from the POST variables
$item_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['item_name']);
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['last_name']);
$payment_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['payment_date']);
$mc_gross = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['mc_gross']);
$payment_currency = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['payment_currency']);
$payment_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['payment_type']);
$payment_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['payment_status']);
$txn_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['txn_type']);
$payment_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['payment_type']);
$payer_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['payer_status']);
$address_street = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['address_street']);
$address_city = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['address_city']);
$address_state = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['address_state']);
$address_zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['address_zip']);
$address_country = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['address_country']);
$address_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['address_status']);
$notify_version = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['notify_version']);
$verify_sign = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['verify_sign']);
$payer_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['payer_id']);
$mc_currency = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['mc_currency']);
$mc_fee = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['mc_fee']);
$txn_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['txn_id']);
$payer_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['payer_email']);
$custom = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['custom']);


// Place the transaction into the database
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare(
    $db_conx,
    "INSERT INTO yt_transactions (product_id_array, payer_email, first_name, last_name, item_name, payment_date, mc_gross, payment_currency, txn_id, receiver_email, payment_type, payment_status, txn_type, payer_status, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country, address_status, notify_version, verify_sign, payer_id, mc_currency, mc_fee) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
);
//after validation, of course
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssssssssssssssssss", $custom, $payer_email, $first_name, $last_name, $item_name, $payment_date, $mc_gross, $payment_currency, $txn_id, $receiver_email, $payment_type, $payment_status, $txn_type, $payer_status, $address_street, $address_city, $address_state, $address_zip, $address_country, $address_status, $notify_version, $verify_sign, $payer_id, $mc_currency, $mc_fee);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_conx))
{
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);//<-- CLEAN UP AFTER YOURSELF!
    //update was successful
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
}

    //mysqli_close($db_conx);
// Mail yourself the details
mail("".$paypal_email."", "You have a payment!", $req, "From: ".$paypal_email."");
?>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some kind of error must be happening.  If you follow the steps in this [guide on how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) you should be able to track it down.

Comment: You don't need to escape your data if you're doing a prepared statement